# jquery ui : $(this).data("ui-draggable") undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I get this error from firebug

```
$(this).data("ui-draggable") undefined
```

In this line of draggable.js jquery file :

```
var t = $("body"), o = $(this).data("ui-draggable").options;
```

I have no idea what to do : here is my pretty simple code :

```
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<div id="draggable"></div>
```

css :

```
#draggable{
    background-color: white;
    width: 107px !important;
    height: 52px !important;
    border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190); 
    margin-top : -7px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:center;  
}
```

and js :

```
$(function() {  
    $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

the line that loads the script comes from kohanna a php framework and works perfectly. I use other jquery widgets that are loaded before this one and they work perfectly.

Any idea ? Thank you !

EDIT : 
- the UI is added before and properly otherwise my others jquery widgets wouldn't work and the draggable.js file is added properly too
- I checked in console and this refers to my div : #draggable

EDIT 2 :

```
<?echo HTML::script('http://s3.amazonaws.com/imgs3.plinga.de/general/shop/plingaShop.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/jquery.multiselect.filter.min.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::style('assets/styles/jquery.multiselect.css'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::style('assets/styles/newshop.css'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::style('assets/styles/jquery.multiselect.filter.css'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::style('assets/styles/jquery.nailthumb.1.1.min.css'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::style('assets/scripts/jquery.nailthumb.1.1.min.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<? if(I18n::$lang == 'de') echo HTML::script("assets/scripts/locale/jquery.multiselect.filter.de.js"),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/plugins/upload/jquery.ui.widget.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/plugins/upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/plugins/upload/jquery.fileupload.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/shop/show.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/newshop/edit.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
<?echo HTML::script('assets/scripts/jquery.ui.droppable.js'),PHP_EOL ?>
```

Comment: Are those PHP shorttags and then a class of some sort? Are you sure that script is added properly in the HTML source ?

Comment: Also, you did add the UI core, widget and mouse libraries **before** the draggable.js

Comment: o = $(this).data("ui-draggable").options;  <---you cant set o here unless $('this') is a valid reference and had a data property called ui-draggable, and somehow that data property was an object that had a property called options

Comment: @Rooster that code is from the jQuery UI draggable widget, it's valid.

Comment: @KevinB : I believe he can't add the console call... that's the error that is getting thrown in Firebug when he runs the page. However, if he could put a breakpoint on the breaking line, he could look at `this` in the console at that point.

Comment: The error is from inside draggable.js, it doesn't matter what `this` is, but it probably references the selector passed to the plugin, which in this case is `#draggable`, not that it matters ?

Comment: I miss-read, i didn't realize initially that an error was actually occurring. Definitely going to be either a dependency issue or a conflict, we're going to need to see all included script includes in the order that they are included, and know what browser(s) you're testing in.

Comment: I'm testing in firefox. chrome throws something else but at the same line : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined". I give you the list of all includes.

Comment: Have you included all the necessary dependencies: UI Core, widget factory, and mouse interaction (see http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edward was right. I forgot to include the depedancies :

- UI Core
- Widget Factory
- Mouse interaction

Thanks!